# multi array usage in foreach loop

Tags: php

I've got the following array stored in a $_SESSION

```
[Bookings] => Array
    (
        [date] => Array
             (
                [0] => 1/12/2013
                [1] => 1/19/2013
                [2] => 2/03/2013
            )

        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] =>  100
                [1] =>  150
                [2] =>  120
             )

   )
```

However I want to use a foreach loop and perform calculation on both values within the array.I can't seem to fugure out how I can use the foreach to accomodate multivalues, I've got a sample of a foreach I wrote below of what I'm trying to achieve. Anyone point me in the right direction.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['Bookings'] as $bookings) 
{
   myDate = $bookings[date];
   myPrice = $bookings[price];

   // Some other stuff here
}
```

Comment: doesn't $myDate[0] give '1/12/2013' ?

Comment: Alternative solution with `MultipleIterator`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14724544/664108

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (array_keys($_SESSION['Bookings']['date']) as $key) 
{
    $myDate  = $_SESSION['Bookings']['date'][$key];
    $myPrice = $_SESSION['Bookings']['price'][$key];
}
```

Should work?

Some info on: [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['Bookings']['date'] as $key => $value) {
    $myDate = $value;
    $myPrice = $_SESSION['Bookings']['price'][$key];
}
```

simpler I guess :)

Comment: Thanks TomTom, yours worked as well.Just been looking into array_keys, which might be useful in the future.I've bumped your answer to useful. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

just loop through on of your subarrays and read the corresponding value from the other

```
foreach ( $_SESSION['Bookings'][ 'date' ] as $key => $myDate) {

    $myPrice = $_SESSION['Bookings'][ 'price' ][ $key ];


    // here you can access to $myDate and $myPrice

    // Some other stuff here
}
```